# Maven dependency - postgres to Oracle

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven, jpa

So far I was using Postgres on my localhost to run as my DB. Everything was ok, I had this dependency in my pom.xml and the following config (note that I didn't have the Driver specified explicitely):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

application.configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://*********
spring.datasource.username=********
spring.datasource.password=*********
```

All good:

```
2020-10-31 13:47:03.078  INFO 28600 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2020-10-31 13:47:04.037  INFO 28600 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8091 (http) with context path ''
2020-10-31 13:47:04.270  INFO 28600 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-10-31 13:47:04.283  INFO 28600 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-10-31 13:47:04.659  INFO 28600 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-10-31 13:47:04.915  INFO 28600 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-10-31 13:47:04.925  INFO 28600 --- [           main] c.a.u.f.FetcherserviceApplication        : Started FetcherserviceApplication in 8.87 seconds (JVM running for 10.334)
```

Now I wanted to switch to an oracle DB, so I've deleted the above postgresql dependency from my pom.xml and added one for Oracle plus deleted the postgres lines from my configuration and added the following:

> ```
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@********
> spring.datasource.username=********
> spring.datasource.password=*********
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
> spring.jpa.datasbase-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
> ```

Now, if at this point I try to rerun the application I see that the Oracle Driver is being picked up but then the application still fails to start after because:

> ```
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.    
> 2020-10-31 14:29:30.746 ERROR 6384 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :    
> ***************************    
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START    
> ***************************    
> Description:    
> Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:    
>     Property: driver-class-name    
>     Value: org.postgresql.Driver    
>     Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"    
>     Reason: Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader    
> Action:    
> Update your application's configuration
> ```

Where is this coming from? I did updated the configuration as described above but more importantly the project shouldn't even know at this point that Postgres ever existed as as I've purged it from the pom.xml. So how is it possible there is an issue with it here?

I assume there is still something I don't understand about how Maven manages dependencies.

Thanks!
/András

Comment: I had something similar recently though I was using gradle so I think this is a spring/ide issue; in the end I went through the code/properties to make sure to remove all references to redis (the database in my case) then refreshed the caches to make sure the new dependency was being loaded and did a clean build. It seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the maven unable to import oracle dependencies automatically. Following will help you to resolve the issue

1. Remove PostgreSQL dependencies from the pom.xml
2. Then add oracle JDBC dependencies to the pom.xml

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

3. Download oracle dependencies and install manually to maven local repository

   mvn install:install-file -Dfile="Your downloaded oracle jar file location" -DgroupId=com.oracle.ojdbc -DartifactId="artifact id" -Dversion="downloaded version number" -Dpackaging=jar
4. Then clean your project and run. It seemed to work.

Comment: Note that the Oracle 10.x driver is completely outdated and should not longer be used. And `ojdbc14` refers to a version intended for Java 1.4 - not for any modern Jav version

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest 19.8 JDBC driver. Refer to this [guide](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html) for more details.
Also, you can use [DataSourceSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java) to verify if everything works fine.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8-production</artifactId>
    <version>19.8.0.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```